# How to make an authorization and access token requests with PKCE

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, azure-functions, pkce

Can you point me to the right way and set of parameters to:

1. Make an authorization request with PKCE to my identity endpoint (https://.../login) in Postman
   In the attachments there is the list of parameters that send.
   as grant_type value I use --> authorization_code
   Unfortunately I get "bad request", Invalid_grant in Postman
   [image]
2. make the access token request. In this request I get Invalid request. I guess I miss the parameter refresh token but I don't know how to get/generate it:
   [image]

I wrote the code of the Azure function to request the Access Token, unfortunately I get {"error":"invalid_request"} from the token endpoint.
Here is my code, can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
[FunctionName("GetAccessToken")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAccessToken(
  [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
  ILogger log)
    {
        try
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function ''GetAccessToken'' processed a request.");

            string clientSecret = "some secret";

            string accessToken = "";     

            RequestAccessToken rT = new RequestAccessToken();
            rT.Code = req.Form["code"];
            rT.RedirectUri = req.Form["redirect_uri"];
            rT.GrantType = req.Form["grant_type"];
            rT.ClientId = req.Form["client_id"];
            rT.CodeVerifier = req.Form["code_verifier"];

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://<access_token_endpoint_base_uri>");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders
                .Accept
                .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));//ACCEPT header

                var body = new { EntityState = new {
                    code = rT.Code,
                    redirect_uri = rT.RedirectUri,
                    grant_type = rT.GrantType,
                    client_id = rT.ClientId,
                    client_secret = clientSecret,
                    code_verifier = rT.CodeVerifier

                } };
                var result = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(
                               "/login",
                               body);
                accessToken = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }             

            return new OkObjectResult(accessToken);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.LogInformation(ex.ToString());

            return new ObjectResult(ex.ToString()) { StatusCode = 500 };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Steps 4 and 8 of my blog post](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/) show the standard PKCE parameters.

It is tricky to reproduce the whole flow via a tool such as Postman though, since there is typically also the need to follow redirects and manage a form post of user + password.

Comment: thank yuo for your answer. I followed step 8 but I get "Invalid_client", my problem is that I don't know where to get "code" value

Comment: An authorization code can only be retrieved by submitting a user + password via the login system. So it is difficult to do via postman. You might want to consider an alternative OAuth flow for automated tests, such as [step 4 of my blog page on load testing](https://authguidance.com/2019/08/02/api-load-test/). Can you add a few notes to your question on the end goal you are trying to achieve and which Authorization Server you are using.

Comment: As regards my end goal: I need to implement 2 API (by means of Azure functions) that perform the authorize (first API) and the access token request (second API) implementing the PKCE pattern. Unfortunately I cannot figure out the exact list of parameters to pass to these APIs so at the moment I am googling for guidance and doing tests with Postman.

Comment: The job of APIs in this setup is to receive tokens then validate them and work with the caller identity. If APIs call each other they should use Client Credentials Flow. PKCE is only ever coded in UIs. I think you should be aiming to get a token (via a different flow to PKCE) then focus on calling APIs and testing their behaviour. Trying to do a PKCE login from Postman is not a good idea. A simpler flow would work better.

Comment: I have Updated my question with the code of the Azure function, thanks.